# How to read fetched data from API?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data and display it in my app. I am fetching the data on initState. However I am facing this error:

[image]

```
 @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    context.read<UseAuth>().fetchUser();
  }
```

and trying to display the data
`Text("${context.watch<UseAuth>().userData.length}")`

Then in my provider file I got

```dart
  User? userData;

  fetchUser() async {
    var response = await fetchUserData(apiClient);
    userData = jsonDecode(response.data).map((json) => User.fromJson(json));
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

How do I make sure my data loads and displays?

Response:

```json
{
  "avatar_url": "https://google.com",
  "description": "Test",
  "id": "0c70bbb5-c3e7-41ac-9c80-5b597449232e",
  "nick": "test"
}
```

```dart
class User {
  String? avatar_url;
  String? description;
  String id;
  String nick;

  User({ this.avatar_url, this.description, required this.id, required this.nick });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return User(
        avatar_url: json['avatar_url'],
        description: json['description'],
        id: json['id'],
        nick: json['nick']
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: please share you build method

Comment: @reza widget build? I just have the `context.watch` thing. Do I need to add something as well? Also, the data I am fetching is a single object. Is `List` appropriate for that or should I use a map?

Comment: please send API  and Response

Comment: @kkweb added response, api is my local backend

Comment: it failed with late initialization you can try to remove `late` keyword using nullable `List<User>? userData;`

Answer (score 0):

make your `userData` nullable and in your build method check if `userData` is null, show loading else use `userData` contents

Comment: Tried like you said, says null all the time. `Text("${context.watch<UseAuth>().userData?.length == null ? 'Loading' : context.watch<UseAuth>().userData?.length }"),`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it would help.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final usersList = context.watch<UseAuth>().userData;
    
    if (usersList == null || usersList?.isEmpty == true)
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    
    return Text("${context.watch<UseAuth>().userData.length}");
 }
```

Let me know if the above code doesn't work.

There are other ways to solve this error as well.

Comment: I keep getting `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. You know what might be wrong?

Comment: I think the error is on the API side. Please share your User.fromJson(json)) method code.

Comment: i've updated my original post, please check, also api side is fine, becuase I am getting a response